# Problem with query on nested document in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to get price and date info and send to ejs the between two specific dates and names.

My first document is like this and I have many. For instance I want all Bitcoin infos between 2022-4-1 and 2022-4-6. Without nested it works but in this case I couldn't do.

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("62175a6dd2b42d83134288f0"),
   "result" : [ 
       {
           "name" : "Bitcoin",
           "symbol" : "BTC",
           "price" : 45488.969940933,
           "date" : "2022-4-1",
           "time" : "16:25:22",
           "active" : 1
       }, 
       {
           "name" : "Ethereum",
           "symbol" : "ETH",
           "price" : 3328.61487109438,
           "date" : "2022-4-1",
           "time" : "16:25:22",
           "active" : 1
       }, 
   //..and goes to 100
      
   ]
}
```

[image: myDocuments]

I've tried

```
dbo.collection("info").find({ result : {name:"Bitcoin"}, date: { $gte: "2022-4-1", $lte: "2022-4-6" }.toArray //Getting an empty []
dbo.collection("info").find({ 'result.name' :"Bitcoin"}).toArray //Getting all of documents in the DB.
dbo.collection("info").find({"result": { $elemMatch:{"name": "Bitcoin"}}}).toArray //Same as above.
```

I have also tried without .toArray and findOne and nothing changed. Many thanks.

First object's full JSON is https://pastebin.com/06V4upPY

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({
  result: {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "Bitcoin",
      date: {
        $gte: "2022-4-1",
        $lte: "2022-4-6"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "result.$": 1
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sJ8Y7wJwpFf)

Comment: I tried but it gives the same result as my last 2 attempts.

Comment: @genzowakabayashi how come. it works good in my [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sJ8Y7wJwpFf). could you show me more test data and tell me which data you want to keep as output.

Comment: I have added first document's JSON to the first post. Other objects are the same, changes only values. My goal is to enter two date ranges and get the price information of the relevant currency. These infos comes from express, my problem is at the query.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that the second and third query return all documents because if all documents have a Bitcoin element in the result array it will return the document.

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field
> with at least one element that matches all the specified query
> criteria.

[Source $elemMatch (query) doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

For filter only the bitcoin element you must $elemMatch in the projection part
Like this :

```
dbo.collection("info").find({ 
  'result.name' :"Bitcoin"
}, 
{
  'result': {
      $elemMatch: {
         "name": "Bitcoin" 
      }
   }
)
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-YWs5p0Eut6)

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results

[Source : $elemMatch (projection) doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

Comment: I tried but it gives the same result as my last 2 attempts.

Comment: Can you provide a bigger dataset ?

Comment: I have added first document's JSON to the first post. Other objects are the same, changes only values.

Comment: I saw you first document but if you check the mongoPlayground the request work for the document provided are you sur you type correctly the request and is the result in the mongo playground is what you expect ?

Comment: The request with you Json updated see: https://mongoplayground.net/p/awjE3VL3S4_

Comment: Actually Playground result is correct. When I run the code on Node console, just cursor is blinking and as I said if my datas was like { "name" : "..." } it still works.

Comment: Have you tried to do the request on other support like mongo Compass ?